# google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', alert("sth")) only works for the 1st time

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', alert("say sth"))` only works for the 1st time the map is loaded. After that, no matter how I dragged the map or zoomed the map, the alert didn't pop up.

Same did `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', alert("just pop twice!"))`.

Comment: Maybe some javascript error after this call prevents it calling again?

Comment: hey @Marcelo, thx 4 replying! I found the problem with the help of @ Dr.Molle, I lost 'function(){}'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the alert into a function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){alert("just pop twice!")})
```

Comment: Thx for replying, @Dr.Molle! I did as u said, it works perfect! Many thx!

Comment: For later readers trying to learn something, a sentence saying "why" this is needed would be educational.